# testar cenário de filtro

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

Gostaria de saber a melhor maneira de testar (com jasmine) um filtro com esse cenário:

```
function districtFilter(city, array) {
    var districtFound = array.filter(function(a) {
        return a.id !== city.id;
    });
    return districtFound;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var array = [
{
  id: 1,
  city: "Washington"
},
{
  id: 2,
  city: "Chicago"
},
{
  id: 3,
  city: "New York"
}];

var city = {
  id: 1,
  city: "Washington"
};

console.log(districtFilter(city, array));
```

Comment: Seria em teste unitário, usando o framework pra teste, jasmine